# Recode values based on look up table with dplyr (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, lookup, recode

A relatively trivial question that has been bothering me for a while, but to which I have not yet found an answer - perhaps because I have trouble verbalizing the problem for search engines.

Here is a column of a data frame that contains identifiers.

```
data <- data.frame("id" = c("D78", "L30", "F02", "A23", "B45", "T01", "Q38", "S30", "K84", "O04", "P12", "Z33"))
```

Based on a lookup table, outdated identifiers are to be recoded into new ones. Here is an example look up table.

```
recode_table <- data.frame("old" = c("A23", "B45", "K84", "Z33"),
                           "new" = c("A24", "B46", "K88", "Z33"))
```

What I need now can be done with a merge or a loop. Here a loop example:

```
for(ID in recode_table$old) {
  data[data$id == ID, "id"] <- recode_table[recode_table$old == ID, "new"]
}
```

But I am looking for a dplyr solution without having to use the " join" family. I would like something like this.

```
    data <- mutate(data, id = ifelse(id %in% recode_table$old, filter(recode_table, old == id) %>% pull(new), id))
```

Obviously though, I can't use the column name ("id") of the table in order to identify the new ID.
References to corresponding passages in documentations or manuals are also appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`recode`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html) with unquote splicing (`!!!`) on a named vector

```
library(dplyr)

# vector of new IDs
recode_vec <- recode_table$new
# named with old IDs
names(recode_vec) <- recode_table$old

data %>% 
  mutate(id = recode(id, !!!recode_vec))
#     id
# 1  D78
# 2  L30
# 3  F02
# 4  A24
# 5  B46
# 6  T01
# 7  Q38
# 8  S30
# 9  K88
# 10 O04
# 11 P12
# 12 Z33
```